Django cant change default language
I have developed a web application in 2 languages, where users can change in-between them using the UI, and it all works fine, the language is changing. What I cant setup is the default language that is working when the application is opened for the first time. This is my settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'az'

USE_I18N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]

LANGUAGES = [
    ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
    ('en', 'English'),
]

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('main.urls')),  # Include your app's URLs
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


Are you sure no cookie has been set, session variables, etc. The process to pick a language is quite complicated.
